# In XCode: How do I Create a main page with icons that lead to different pages

Tags: xcode

OK, im new to xcode. how would I...

-Create an opening page that goes in a couple of seconds (the first page with my logo on)

-Create the main page with about 4 icons on that would lead to different pages

-Create a table view list that links to other pages

-Also when using the 'table view' how do i edited the writing, iv tried double clicking.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is no short answer for this. If i were you I would read the documentation and take baby steps from there.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/00-About_the_iOS_Application_Development_Workflow/introduction.html

Also when you are ready, check apple sample code library.